# findBy() returning null but db is full

Tags: php, symfony, class, doctrine, repository

I have to db tables where I need to compare two ids. In table one I have $id and in other I have $previousId.

First table id is found by query builder and second I need to find by repository that I set.

Every time I dump() results it returns [] even if I have mulitple fields in my database with previousId values.

My code:

```
 public function myMethod($previousId)
{
    $tableOne = $this->getTableOneRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->select('e')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $tableTwo = $this->getTableTwoRepository()->findBy(['previousId' => $previousId]);

     dump(tableTwo);die;  ----// returns [] even I if have table data

        if($tableOne->getId() == $tableTwo->getPreviousId){
            throw new \Exception('This message is already been archived.');
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello there and welcome to the forum. Your question unfortunately is missing much of the related code so it's pretty much guesswork what of the many potential places might be bugging. But you can easily start narrowing down the options yourself: pick a value that surely exists in the tableTwo and hard code that into the repository call: "failure" (still returning empty) => your repository getter or the param usage is bugging, and "success" (returns values) => something in the logic that passes the $previousId parameter to this method is bugging...

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks a lot! @ejuhjav